# I am having trouble trying to fix TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

[Grades.txt file](https://pastebin.com/ZViCXL2b)

I am currently trying to finish a assignment but I am confused on how to fix this error. I am creating a program that will analyzes grades from a file and should calculate the
average score for each distinct section (given). I receive the error for

sections[sec]["total"] = grade[grade]

```
grades = {'A': 100, 'B': 89, 'C': 79, 'D': 74, 'F': 69}

# this section reads the file


def calculate_average():
    file = open("grades.txt", "r")
    sections = {}
    for line in file:
        [_, sec, grade] = line.split("\t")
        grade = grade.strip()
        if sec in sections:
            sections[sec]["count"] += 1
            sections[sec]["total"] += grade[grade]
        else:
            sections[sec] = {}
            sections[sec]["count"] = 1
            sections[sec]["total"] = grade[grade]
    file.close()

# This section calculates the average data based on file

    for sec, secdata in sections.items():
        avg = secdata[" total "] / secdata[" count"]
        print(" {0} : {1}".format(sec, round(avg, 2)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    calculate_average()
```

Comment: Without knowing what the file content of `grades.txt` is, it's hard to say what will happen. Please provide a [mre]. Don't use user input, don't use file input. Use some hard coded example data

Comment: typo should be grades[grade]

Comment: Is the issue with `grade[grade]`, Should this be `grades[grade]`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean:

```
sections[sec]["total"] = grades[grade]
```